# Why does \if in a tikzpicture evaluate to true for \if 33 \empty?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcount\x \x=-1
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \percentA in {33}
  {
    \if \percentA \empty \else
    \global\advance\x by 1
     \draw (\x,0) circle (0.2cm);
     \fi
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I use `\if` instead of `\ifx`, this code compiles to an empty document. If I would use `66` instead of `33`, it would compile to an empty document as well. But if I would use any other value (like `32` or `34` or `65`), it would work just fine, and would draw a circle.

Could somebody tell me why `33` equals to `\empty`? I know that I should have used `\ifx`, but I'm wondering why `33` and `66` are so special in this case, because I would expect the same behavior for every number.

Comment: `\if` expands tokens until it finds two non-expandable tokens. So `\if\percentA \empty` turns into `\if33\empty`, then `3` and `3` are compared and the result is true, so `\empty` is executed.

Comment: What would be the reason to compare `\percentA` to `\empty` anyway? Could you please be more explicit about your real aim?

Comment: @egreg I wanted to generate a pie chart, and found [this example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/pie-chart-color/) as I was changing this to fit my purposes I somehow changed ifx to if.

Comment: @stiefel The `\ifx\percent\empty\else` line is completely useless, because with the given data `\percent` is never empty. Remove it and the final `\fi`.